# If our nation takes on debt now that will have to be paid by gen z later isn't that taxation without representation?

Tags: tax-law, us-constitution, debt

We have representatives but gen z does not. How is it fair to spend their money before they are even old enough to have a say? Was the idea of pushing debt onto future generations so unthinkable that it is a constitutional blind spot?

Comment: 1. You misunderstand the concept of "representation" in that infamous quote, 2. This is more a question for the Politics or Philosophy SE, not here, you aren't asking about anything to do with the law.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not suited for this site, it belongs on either Politics SE or Philosophy SE.

Comment: 1. I absolutely do not misunderstood the concept or "representation" and I also knew you would think that but hoped you wouldn't. 2. If you choose to not answer it with respect to law then no it isn't. But it's very obvious that there is as much room as anyone would need to include the law in an answer to this question.

Comment: Serious consideration of future generations has only recently started to seriously enter into the political process and discourse as anything beyond manipulative rhetoric, and then really only in a very small number of areas and locations.  The western/european world simply never conceived of that as an issue worthy of consideration; subsequent generations will deal with their problems in their own time, and that was expected to be fine.  The idea that present day people could seriously ruin things for later generations, in a way they could do nothing about, was nigh inconceivable.

Comment: This is a question of what the laws, and particularly the constitution permit, and of the legal history which formed the constitution,. As such it is on-topic here in my view, although it would also be on-topic in Politics.

Comment: Future generations have option to default or restructure debt.

Answer (score 10):

### No

"No taxation without representation!" was a slogan of the US war of independence, but it was never put into the Constitution. Indeed, the residents of the District of Columbia and Puerto Rico now pay Federal income tax, but are not represented in the Congress that sets the taxes.

National debt has some of the same economic effects of a tax, but it is not a tax in form nor in constitutional law. Constitutional limits on tax legislation (such as the rule against unapportioned direct taxes) do not apply to congressional borrowing.

"Representation", in the sense you mean, has never been applied to representatives of future generations, or even of people not yet of voting age.

> Was the idea of pushing debt onto future generations so unthinkable that it is a constitutional blind spot?

Quite the reverse. Borrowing was initiated quite early, while many of the framers were still in government. In several places in the Federalist Papers, Hamilton emphasized the need for an unlimited power to tax, for, among other purposes, paying any national debts, and made it clear that such debts would be incurred, from time to time. See particularly Nos 30 and 41.

In [*The Federalist* No 30](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/fed30.asp) Hamilton wrote:

> In the modern system of war, nations the most wealthy are obliged to have recourse to large loans. A country so little opulent as ours must feel this necessity in a much stronger degree. But who would lend to a government that prefaced its overtures for borrowing by an act which demonstrated that no reliance could be placed on the steadiness of its measures for paying? The loans it might be able to procure would be as limited in their extent as burdensome in their conditions.

This is part of a longer argument to the effect that a lack of power by the Federal Government to levy individual taxes would be disastrous. Here Hamilton certainly seems to contemplate the Federal government borrowing in case of war or other emergency, and repaying such loans by future taxes.

In [*The Federalist* No 41](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/fed41.asp) Madison wrote;

> The powers falling within the FIRST class [Security against foreign danger] are those of declaring war and granting letters of marque; of providing armies and fleets; of regulating and calling forth the militia; of levying and borrowing money. Security against foreign danger is one of the primitive objects of civil society. It is an avowed and essential object of the American Union. ... If a federal Constitution could chain the ambition or set bounds to the exertions of all other nations, then indeed might it prudently chain the discretion of its own government, and set bounds to the exertions for its own safety.

This again seems to contemplate an unlimited power of borrowing money by the government (or limited only by its available credit) to be repaid from taxes.  Thus at least two of the founders considered this issue, and it was in now way part of a "blind spot".

When he became the first Secretary of the Treasury, Hamilton embarked on his famous program of encouraging manufactures, funding needed "improvements" (of roads and harbors, in particular) largely by borrowing. These proposals were openly, widely, and heatedly debated both in Congress and out of it, before Congress authorized them. The argument that such debts would have to be repaid out of future tax revenue was indeed advanced, although not, as far as I know, precisely in the terms this question uses. But the issue was generally considered by the public, which was in no way blind to the future effects of present borrowing by the government. It was not a later innovation, unthoguht-of by the founders and early governments of the US.

In short the Constitution does not contain any requirement such as the question suggests, and was never intended to do so, because the founders felt it essential to allow the government an unlimited power to borrow money, limited only by the needs of the case and the sound judgement of Congress.

Comment: Here's the basic problem. I say something that you could choose to interpret as being dumb. Your response is then centered around that interpretation. I know what I said and that is as far as I will go. I have doubts about your answer.

Comment: @user875234  The question appears to me to reflect a mistatement of fact, I have no idea how you interpreted it. If there are specific aspects of my answer that you think are incorrect, or have doubts about, you are free to mention them. f you choose to do so, I will attempt to address them. Others may choose to offer answers. I don't assume that you,m or your question is foolish or "dumb". But as written it does seem to me to include some inaccuracies.

Comment: To the extent that the OP might feel this doesn't address the question "Was the idea of pushing debt onto future generations so unthinkable that it is a constitutional blind spot?" I agree. You say it is not in the constitution and was never conceived to be in the constitution. Sounds like it could be seen as a "blind spot".

Comment: @George White I also mention that the issue of government borrowing was discussed in detail during the ratification debates, including by Hamilton in *The Federalist* in more than one place. Then Hamilton acted on that view, and those actions were a matter of widespread and heated debate at the time. It does not sound to me as if that possibility was ignored or was "unthinkable". Whether modern practice would have commended itself to the Founders is another question, one much harder to answer.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: @George White  I have now edited my answer to directly quoet two numbers of *The Federalist* and otherwise support my argument.